# Using sed to save result in buffer and use it as pattern for another sed command

Tags: sed, scripting

So I came to know about the existence of buffer in sed (pattern buffer, hold buffer, etc) and thought if there was an easy way to hold/save or just reuse the result of a sed command (eg: substitution) for another command/sed invocation?

Say I'm doing substitution from the output of a pipe:

```bsh
somecommand | sed 's/somepattern/somethingelse/g'
```

And i want to somehow reuse the output of the substitution above, how could i do it? I know i could just use:

1. A tempfile (eg: using primitive mv + echo etc)
2. Another set of pipe, sed invocation and xargs (eg: sed ... | xargs -I{} sed ...)

But both of the above would prevent me from *only* using a single invocation of sed (which is what I want to do here).

If there was such a way known to me, I would then just do:

```bsh
somecommand | sed -i 's/somepattern/somethingelse/g;s/[reusing result from last substitution]/someotherthings/g' file
```

Where the part between [] would be reusing the result of the substitution as pattern or for something else...

I did try and look up any possible solutions on the sed documentation but there wasn't much example if any leading to this.

Any feedback/answer appreciated.

P.S.: The output of the examples above isn't really the focus here, but to make things clearer, the `somecommand` could be replaced to this:

```bsh
echo "hello"
```

Literally.

Here another thing i tried, that will serve as a more understandable example:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
echo -e "hello\nworld" | sed -n '
l #enable debugging
'/hello/' { # match the string from the echo pipe/command output
    s/hello/test/ #do a substitution
    p #print
    x # keep in
}'
```

I managed to do the first half; Now I need to know how to use what reside in `x` so i could, say, use it for another substitution (or any other sed invocation/action/command)...

Here what I tried (but this time failed):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
echo -e "hello\nworld" | sed -n '
l #enable debugging
'/hello/' { # match the string from the echo pipe/command output
    s/hello/test/ #do a substitution
    p #print
    x # keep in
    s/x/somethingelse/ # <---- what is failing
}'
```

This doesn't work. I'm guessing there a way to get whatever content is in `x` here but I don't know it.

Comment: Can you be more specific and providw a concrete input/expected output set?

Comment: there isn't any? the `somecommand` just output an example string of small lenght (length here doesn't matter much), then some action is done by the first sed command (here I took the liberty to make it substitute to some example pattern) *then* reuse the output of the previous sed command, but as pattern for another actino (eg: another substitution) and as seen on the very last example, and for more clarity, done on a file... @guest_7

Comment: The main thing I want to know here is mainly how i could easily save the output of a sed command, without using the two method i described in my post *and* reuse it as a pattern for another set of sed command :) (the documentation didn't help much in that regard) @guest_7

Comment: when using `sed 's/pattern1/replace1/g;s/pattern2/replace2/g'` sed will remplace pattern1 by replace1, then `replace1` is **discarded** from sed's memory but, of course, keep in output file. There is no way to reuse `replace1` inside `pattern2`

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to do (following your example) `sed 's/pattern1/replace1/g;s/pattern2/replace2/g'` but instead `sed 's/pattern1/replace1/g;s/[reuse result of last substitution]/replace2/g'`...and I know it's possible because I seen some command hold/keep result from one sed invocation into a buffer, and use it for other command...but the documentation isn't the best in showing clear example of this @Archemar

Comment: Even a hypothetical input/output data will do. But that has to come from you, bcoz if we were to use our own , then the I/O gets biased by our understanding of the pbm leading to possible inaccuracies and iterations. Till the time an I/O is not readied and we talk in prose nothing much will happen. Also, strange as it may sound, when you get down to writing the I/O , the solution might present itself.

Comment: that's totally understandable and I agree in what you say, *but* I think i already provided everything i needed for the examples above and in the comment, unless of course i forgot to include something, feel free to tell me and I'll add it in :) (I would be able to provide clearer example but problem is, I don't know how to do what I'm describing, otherwise I would have done so) @guest_7

Comment: When you say in the 2nd step use the result of the previous step...but that info is the current pattern space. Correct me uf I'm wrong.

Comment: Also, even if a solution is given to you how would you test it?

Comment: I would test it using the example above or any kind of example where there 1. a sed invocation (as said before, let's say it's a substitution from string1 to string2) 2. taking into account that, we can use the result using whatever method is known to save/pass the result of the first substitution to another sed command/action (eg: can be anything else, maybe `/p` just to see if it work or another substitution) @guest_7

Comment: And yes, I believe this is as you said (the pattern space). @guest_7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124465/discussion-between-nordine-lotfi-and-guest-7).

Comment: I added more examples that I think can be considered more detailed. @guest_7

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what your question is, but isn't the modified line already available by default? For example: `printf 'hello\nworld\n' | sed -n '/hello/{s//test/; p; s/t/XYZ/g; p}'`

Comment: it's hard to fully explain in detail because of the character limits, but did you see the new edit i did to my post? (on the last two example in the PS part). I think those encapsulate more what I'm trying to do here. @Sundeep

Comment: My code was based on the new edit (I copied the hello/test parts)...

Comment: In your hello world example, what is the output you expect to see?

Comment: @Archemar Yes there is a way to resuse `replace1` inside `pattern2` via the hold space. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you, you want some kind of dynamic search pattern by using the output of a past substitution as pattern for another replacement.

I find it helpful to work with examples. Given a file like

```
green2
gold1
blue3
gold2
red4
more gold2 to find
```

Now you want to replace each `1` by a `2` and store the resulting line to do something when it occurs again. In this example file you would want to replace `gold2` but you can't know, because in another file it could be different. The output is suppose to be

```
green2
gold2
blue3
replace
red4
more replace to replace
```

There can be similar real world tasks and you usually handle those in `sed` like this:

```
sed -e 's/1/2/;tfound' -e 'G;s/\(..*\)\(.*\)\n\1$/replace\2/;P;d' -e ':found' -e h inputfile
```

The concept is to store the resulting line in hold buffer and use a backreference to match each line against the hold buffer. In detail:

- `s/1/2/` is the obvious part: you replace a `1` by `2`
- `tfound` means to branch to mark `:found` in case a replacement was made. In this case, the line is stored in the hold space with `h` and the line with the replacement is printed (if you don't want to print it, you could add a `d`elete)
- Now comes the part for lines to check for the occurence of our hold space pattern: `G` appends the hold space to the current pattern space, so the pattern space consists of
- `s/\(..*\)\(.*\)\n\1$/replace\2/` forms two groups in the current line: The first one is repeated as `\1` after the newline, so this is the dynamic pattern in hold space (note that `..*` requires the pattern to be at least one char, so we avoid an empty hold space to match); the second one is the rest of the line that must not be deleted, so we recylce it as `\2` in the replacement
- We could print the line, if a replacement was made, but if there was no replacement, we have to remove the appended stuff. We could do so by `s/\n.*//`, but we can also use the `P` command to only print the first line, then `d`elete to avoid default output.

This is limited to replacing only one occurence of the dynamic search pattern in the line, but you can easily add a loop to make it work for multiple replacements.

**Update:**
The OP clarified, the second stage should also be applied to the original matching line and all following lines (until a new match), so

```
hello
world
and test it
```

is supposed to become

replace
world
and replace it

In this case you use the same mechanism with different glue logic:

```
sed -ne '/hello/{s//test/;h;}' -e 'G;s/\(..*\)\(.*\)\n\1$/replace\2/;P'
```

Option `-n` suppresses all default output, because all desired output is done by `P` command now. For the matching string (`hello`), the substitution is performed (empty pattern means to reuse the last pattern) and place it in hold buffer, then execute the following commands, so next substitution is done in the same line as well.

**Update 2:**
In the linked example, the `hello` lines should not be modified at all. You can do this with a little modification:

```
sed -ne '/hello/{h;s//test/;x;}' -e 'G;s/\(..*\)\(.*\)\n\1$/replace\2/;P'
```

Comment: btw, It sadly doesn't work for the second substitution (using the example in my post with "hello\nworld").

Comment: Maybe because I didn't understand the supposed output of your example. You change `hello` to `test`, but there is no `test` in your file. Do you also want to apply the second stage to the original line (in my example the second line should also be `replace`)? You can easily modify the logic of my script: `sed -e 's/hello/test/;Tskip' -e h -e ':skip' -e 'G;s/\(..*\)\(.*\)\n\1$/somethingelse\2/;P;d' inputfile`

Comment: Or using a command group instead of a branch: `sed -e '/hello/{s//test/;h;}' -e 'G;s/\(..*\)\(.*\)\n\1$/replace\2/;P;d'`. If this is what you actually expect, I can include it in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, would love if this was included in your answer :D Thanks for greatly detailing everything like this, this help a lots. Also, could you take into account if the inputfile contain the (following above example) the match "test" after the first substitution? so it can replace it on the second substitution but on the actual file this time

Comment: Just seen your edit; this time it does work great and both substitution work as expected, only...it seems it does the two substitution on both the file and the stdin output. see [this](https://gist.github.com/secemp9/435ec1a6bc634c93b18ccd055c4d7ff4) for more context.

Comment: yeah, but I mean, the first version (with `tfound`) doesn't work on the second substitution, but the second version (with your edit) work except on the file I showed in the link on my last comment. (where it work only if the "test" string isn't in-between the string "hello" or/and "test")

Comment: Because you have different requirements between both examples, in the linked one you want the `hello` line to stay unchanged, while in the `hello world` example you want the `hello` line be changed to `test` and then be further changed to `replace`. Decide which behaviour you actually want.

Comment: My bad; I guess this was a miscommunication on my part -- what i want is just for the "test" string to be changed _on the file_, of course, the "hello" string (following the example) will only/already be changed on the first substitution (which is only found/to be found from the stdin of the pipe), here I'm mainly talking about the second substitution. Do tell me if this makes sense

Comment: I still don't understand which version you want or your differentiation between *file* and *stdin* (you can use `sed` on either of them). I updated to give another version to match the linked requirement. If you still want it different, I think I explained how it works to you can adapt it by yourself. Good luck!